What proportion of the universe has a completely dark sky?
How much of the universe has a completely dark sky?
To clarify, I mean “dark” to the unaided human eye. By “completely dark”, I mean there are no persisting lighted images (such as stars or galaxies) against the sky’s dark background.
In the complete absence of light, with fully dark adapted eyes, humans still see transient visual phenomenon due to neuronal noise and the Ganzfeld effect. However, these effects are transient and would not be mistaken for celestial objects.
We live in a galactic cluster. But there are very few galaxies in our local cluster which are visible to the unaided eye (examples: Andromeda, M33, or M101). If we were not distracted by the multitude of neighborhood stars, there would be very few galaxies to see.
If we were outside our galaxy, say half way between the Milky Way and Andromeda, there would be very few celestial objects to see, just a few local-cluster galaxies.
Presumably if a human observer were not in a cluster, but in a cosmic void  where the nearest galaxy was more than10m light years away, there would be no celestial objects to see and the sky would be completely black to the unaided eye.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Large-scale_structure_of_light_distribution_in_the_universe.jpg
The sky would be the antithesis of JWST’s Deep Field pictures or the Star Trek experience.
[]2https://webbtelescope.org/contents/media/images/2022/035/01G7DCWB7137MYJ05CSH1Q5Z1Z
For an intrepid intergalactic voyager, what proportion of a voyage would be passed in regions of featureless dark sky?
Some may suggest this question should be migrated to astronomy. But it deals with the human experience of space travel, like “could you ice skate on Europa”. What would ice-skating be like on Europa?

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50619/what-1-x-1-region-is-the-optically-darkest-patch-in-the-sky
